# What device to use to share LAN's internet?

Tags: ubuntu, networking, lan, internet-connection, connection-sharing

See what I want to do:-

In my department, my boss's desktop is connected to department's LAN via cable wire by which he also surfs internet.

Whenever I too have to use internet, I pull out LAN wire from his desktop and plug it into my laptop. 
Now that's creating difficulty to both of us.

I want to know what device should I use, so that I & my boss both can use LAN's internet simultaneously?

We both are using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS in our system.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use one these regardless what is your OS.

**Hub**
A common connection point for devices in a network. Hubs are commonly used to connect segments of a LAN. A hub contains multiple ports. When a packet arrives at one port, it is copied to the other ports so that all segments of the LAN can see all packets.

**Switch**
In networks, a device that filters and forwards packets between LAN segments. Switches operate at the data link layer (layer 2) and sometimes the network layer (layer 3) of the OSI Reference Model and therefore support any packet protocol. LANs that use switches to join segments are called switched LANs or, in the case of Ethernet networks, switched Ethernet LANs.

**Router**
A device that forwards data packets along networks. A router is connected to at least two networks, commonly two LANs or WANs or a LAN and its ISP.s network. Routers are located at gateways, the places where two or more networks connect. Routers use headers and forwarding tables to determine the best path for forwarding the packets, and they use protocols such as ICMP to communicate with each other and configure the best route between any two hosts.

definitions from [webopedia](http://www.webopedia.com/DidYouKnow/Hardware_Software/router_switch_hub.asp).

Now you can just get one of them and enjoy :).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will consult it with my local dealer to find out appropriate available device.

Comment: Don't use a hub - hubs are really only good for certain types of packet captures. The choice between switch or router will vary greatly depending the rest of the infrastructure. Do you know what is on the other side of that cable you are plugging into?

Comment: Ok , so couple of weeks ago, I brought  a wireless router (bcoz switch was much costly), which has 1 LAN port and 1 WAN port. I'm now able to connect all my systems to internet via Wifi.